# how do I create a package name for the google play console

Tags: android, google-play

Publishing an app on the Google play developer console. This looks like in the documentation like html. What exactly would it be, the app pkg name. There is a box to put it in. Can you make it easy for me this is my first time publishing an app.

Answer (score 1):

[From the Android doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id):

> Every Android app has a unique application ID that looks like a Java
>   package name, such as com.example.myapp. This ID uniquely identifies
>   your app on the device and in Google Play Store.

You can choose the id you want but it should be unique and should also be defined in your `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        ...
    }
}
```