# React Native and Google Sheets API - What should package name and bundle identifier be?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-sheets

I am creating a react native app, and would like to read from and write to Google Sheets spreadsheets.

I am using the Google Sheets API.  When creating an OAuth Client ID in the Google Cloud Platform, I am asked for a package name (for Android) and a bundle identifier (for IOS).  However, i do not have the android manifest or info.plist files so cannot get these.

Any suggestions on what to do would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating "OAuth Client ID" for Android or iPhone? Are you going to deploy the app for iOS and Android? Have you already started the process to publish the app in the Google Play store or the App Store? I think you will get the package name and the bundle identifier from there.
You can read more information about the package name in the [Play Developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#package)

And the Bundle ID from the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/bundle_ids)

And more general information about those Client IDs in the [Help Center article](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849#installedapplications&android&zippy=%2Cnative-applications%2Candroid%2Cios)

Comment: The issue is I do not plan to publish (yet).  Surely there is a way to use the Sheets API before you first publish your app?

Comment: Is it for testing under Android devices using an .apk and iOS devices using .ipa?

Comment: I found this for Android, which mentioned how to create a package name for Android. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939432/how-do-i-create-a-package-name-for-the-google-play-console)